# Pygame creating infinite amount of enemies

Tags: python, pygame

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.speedx = 10
        self.speedy = 10
        self.randomint = random.randint(0, 3)

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(enemyImage, (self.x, self.y))

    def move(self):
        if self.randomint == 0:
                self.x -= self.speedx
                self.y -= self.speedy
        if self.randomint == 1:
                self.x += self.speedx
                self.y -= self.speedy
        if self.randomint == 2:
                self.x -= self.speedx
                self.y += self.speedy
        if self.randomint == 3:
                self.x += self.speedx
                self.y += self.speedy
        if self.x == 0 or self.x == 768:
            self.speedx = -self.speedx
        if self.y == 0 or self.y == 568:
            self.speedy = -self.speedy

def drawGame():
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    robot.draw(screen)
    for bullet in robot.bullets:
        bullet.drawBullet()
    for enemy in enemies:
        enemy.draw(screen)
    pygame.time.delay(30)
    pygame.display.update()

robot = Player(400, 300)
enemies = []

running = True
while running:
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False 


    enemy = Enemy(400, 200)

    enemies.append(enemy)
    for enemy in enemies:
        enemy.move()

    userInput = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    robot.shoot()
    robot.movePlayer(userInput)

    drawGame()
```

I thought this section of code could be useful for determining my problem. Running this code infinitely spawns enemies at the designated x and y value. Since I'm only calling one instance of the class Enemy, I thought only one enemy would spawn with a random movement direction. Why is this occurring instead? Thanks

Comment: you... you appended the enemy to a list of enemies... you should probably not do that, just generate one. It's generating every enemy in the list because you keep adding enemies to the list.

Comment: You create a new enemy at each iteration of the loop. What did you think would happen?

Comment: "Since I'm only calling one instance of the class Enemy" In your own words, why do you think this is true? In your own words, what does `while running:` mean? What will happen each time through the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're problem seems to be caused by the enemy class being called within the 'while running:' loop you have, meaning that for every iteration of that game loop it will generate the enemy without end. Calling the enemy class and appending it to your list outside of that loop should fix the problem

```
robot = Player(400, 300)
enemy = Enemy(400, 200)
enemies = []
enemies.append(enemy)

running = True
while running:
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False 


    
    for enemy in enemies:
        enemy.move()

    userInput = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    robot.shoot()
    robot.movePlayer(userInput)

    drawGame()
```